# SQL sum column in one table where value in another table is 'S'

Tags: sql, informix

I have 2 tables:

```
[rolls]
tappi zone poids
N1001 101 502
N1002 102 502
N1003 103 1008
N1004 104 1008

[zones]
nom  type
101   P
102   P
103   S
104   S
```

What I want to do is sum 'rolls'.'poids' if 'rolls'.'zone' has the type 'S' (according to table 'zones')

Output should be 2016 (1008+1008)

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`, `SUM()`.  What have you tried?

Comment: This sounds like a standard aggregation.  With the data you've posted, what would you want to get out of it?

Comment: i'm very begining in sql so i googled some answer but i cant understand any of em. I'm looking for a sample code to learn from it.

Comment: output should look like: 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(t1.poids)
FROM rolls t1
INNER JOIN zones t2
    ON t1.zone = t2.nom
WHERE t2.type = 'S'
```

We can safely do an `INNER JOIN` here because if a record from `rolls` does not match to anything in `zones` then we know that it cannot be zone type `S`.

Comment: Disclaimer: Gordon answered this in his head way before I penned this answer.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT SUM(rolls.poids) FROM rolls JOIN zones ON rolls.zone = zones.nom WHERE zones.types ='S';

By using **JOIN** we are looking for the the data that the **rolls table** and **zones table** have and by using **ON** we are limiting to find the data where they have an column in common. The goal here is to combine these tables. So that would happen:

```
[[rolls] JOINED [zones]]
tappi zone poids nom type
N1001 101 502    101 P
N1002 102 502    102 P
N1003 103 1008   103 S
N1004 104 1008   104 S
```

Using the where we would segment even more our query to find only records with type **S**. So now you are looking at:

```
[[rolls] JOINED [zones]]
tappi zone poids nom type
N1003 103 1008   103 S
N1004 104 1008   104 S
```

And even further you would be looking for this record and saying to yourself. I just want the sum of the poids. So then you use a **SELECT SUM(rolls.poids)** and the final result is:

```
[sum(rolls.poids)]
   2016
```

Comment: This answer would be improved if you added an explanation.

Comment: @devlincarnate did not see your comment or I would have edited before. Hope it is better now. Cheers